# Deck transformation Calculations.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Is there any source for the detailed calculations for the Deck Transformations stated on pg.70 in AT given below:

[image]

Comment: What is AT ?....

Comment: @JeanMarie Allen Hatcher's book

Comment: This is discussed on the following pages

Comment: @Thorgott do you know where exactly in the following pages, please?

Comment: Actually, you just need the following paragraph where Hatcher recalls that a deck transformation is uniquely determined by where it sends a single point. This, if you fix a basepoint in $\tilde{X}$, sending a deck transformation to the image of this basepoint under it furnishes an injection of $G(\tilde{X})$ into the fiber of $p$ that basepoints lies in. In the examples here, you just have to check the maps are indeed pairwise distinct deck transformations and every point in the fiber is in the image of one (which then implies that there cannot be any more deck transformations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a consequence of Theorem 2 in Chapter 2, Section 6 of E.H. [Spanier's AT](https://ramamishrasite.files.wordpress.com/2019/08/edward-h.-spanier-algebraic-topology-mcgraw-hill-inc-1966.pdf), if $p:\tilde X\rightarrow X$ is a covering projection, then we have an isomorphism $$\psi: G(p)\rightarrow N(p_*\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x_0))/p_*\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x_0)$$ defined by $\psi(f)=[p\circ w_f]$ where $w_f$ is a path from $\tilde x_0$ the $f(\tilde x_0)$. In particular, **if $p$ is regular** then
$$G(p)\cong \pi_1(X,x_0)/p_*\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x_0).$$

1. For the regular covering projection $p:\Bbb R\rightarrow S^1$, $\pi_1(\Bbb R,0)=0$, so $G(P)\cong\pi_1(S^1,1)=\Bbb Z.$ The automorphism $n\in G(p)$ is $n(x)=x+n.$
2. For the regular covering projection $p:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ defined by $p(z)=z^n$, we have $p_*\pi_1(S^1,1)=n\Bbb Z$ hence $G(p)=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z_n.$ The automorphism $k\in G(p)$ is $k(z)=e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{n}}z.$